# Dropbear installation in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, permissions, ssh

I have an assignment to work with Dropbear for SSH connection. First I need to download, configure and install Dropbear.

I downloaded it from https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/

I did:

```
./config
make clean
make
```

When I write `make install`, I get the message:

```
install -d /sbin
install dropbear /sbin
install: cannot remove '/sbin/dropbear': Permission denied
Makefile:182: recipe for target 'inst_dropbear' failed
make: *** [inst_dropbear] Error 1
```

I tried to type `sudo make install`, as suggested in earlier posts, but it doesn't change. What can I do?

Comment: Please repeat from make clean > make > **sudo** make install. Any change?

Comment: Read the error message carefully. It's telling you something.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not invent the wheel.

The Dropbear is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/dropbear) for ages on Debian and Ubuntu.

To install it open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install dropbear
```

To modify the source - enable Source Code in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`), install build dependencies, get the source, modify it, compile and install compiled version by

```
sudo apt-get build-dep dropbear
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev fakeroot

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source dropbear
cd dropbear-*
# modify source

dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
# install modified version
sudo apt-get install ../dropbear{_,-bin,-run}*.deb
```

Comment: part of my assignment is to add a command-line switch (e.g. dropbear -U) that will make dropbear wait for UDP packet. so I need to install it first

Comment: @OzHarary And this command IS to install it! Always prefer packages already in  repositories. Only when there's no such software already available you may try compiling from source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `sudo` permissions on that machine? The simplest test is

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

If that gives you a "permission denied" error, you don't. In that case, you need to build the software with a *prefix*; in your case (since you will also not have permissions for `/usr/local`) to a subdirectory of your home directory and invoke it from there.

See also

https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/master/INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand my mistake. I thought I need to type "sudo make install" and in addition to type make install. so sudo make install was enough